Type checker cannot find attribute "year" on class "pandas.DatetimeIndex"
I'm writing functions that act on pandas.Series with a DatetimeIndex. I can tell the type checker that the Series does not have just any Index, but a DatetimeIndex, using typing.cast (see this question):
import pandas as pd
import typing

def filter_year(s: pd.Series, year: int) -> pd.Series:
    s.index = typing.cast(pd.DatetimeIndex, s.index)
    keep = s.index.year == year
    return s[keep]

Before adding the cast line, I had an error Cannot access attribute "year" for class "Index", which made sense, because pd.Index.year does not exist (AttributeError: type object 'Index' has no attribute 'year')
However, after adding the cast line, I STILL had the error, now Cannot access attribute "year" for class "DatetimeIndex". This I do not understand, as pd.DatetimeIndex.year DOES exist (<property at 0x15ceafc90>).
How can I make my typechecker see the errors of its ways?

Which typechecking tool you are using?. I did test with mypy, it works fine.

I'm using flake8

Hold on. I just uninstalled flake8 and the messages didn't go away. Hmm. One sec, I think it's coming in via trouble.nvim

Ok, it's pyright

Do you have pandas-stubs installed ? https://pypi.org/project/pandas-stubs/
